# Proving that a solution to a differential equation is monotonic

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, logarithms, mathematical-physics, average

The answer that ws given on a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3057171/average-of-a-function-that-comes-out-of-a-complicated-de) of mine, stated that the solution to this DE:

$$x(t)\cdot r+x'(t)\cdot l+a\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{x(t)}{b}\right)=0\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x(t)=\dots\tag1$$

Must be monotonic.

Is there a way to proof that that is the case, that the function $x(t)$ is monotonic?!

---

**Background:**

I've to find (the average of a function over a particular interval, where $t_1>0$, $t_2>0$ and $t_2>t_1$):

$$\frac{1}{t_2-t_1}\int_{t_1}^{t_2}x(t)dt\tag2$$

Where $x(t)$ in equation $(2)$ is the solution to the DE in equation $(1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the DE

$$
l x'+r x+a\ln\left(1+\frac xa\right)=0
$$

taking it's derivative (assuming $x$ is twice diferentiable)

$$
\frac{a x'}{b \left(\frac{x}{b}+1\right)}+l x''+r x' = 0
$$

after substituting $x'$ from the first equation we get

$$
l x''= \frac{(a+b r+r x) \left(a \ln \left(\frac{b+x}{b}\right)+r x\right)}{l (b+x)}
$$

and now solving for $x$ the condition $lx'' = 0$ we obtain

$$
x^* = \{\frac ar W\left(\frac{b e^{\frac{b r}{a}} r}{a}\right)-b,-\left(b+\frac ar\right)\}
$$

also regarding the first equation we have

$$
l x'=-\left(r x+a\ln\left(1+\frac xa\right)\right) = 0\Rightarrow x^* = \frac ar W\left(\frac{b e^{\frac{b r}{a}} r}{a}\right)-b
$$

so the only stationary point has null $x''$ so it is an inflexion point indicating that $x$ is monotonic..

Comment: You assumed it's double differentiable.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Yes. I assumed that. (Included in the last edit).

Comment: Why did you take $lx'' = 0$?

Comment: @LucasHenrique I think that now the conclusion is the correct one.

Comment: @Cesareo So $x(t)$ is monotonous? As I conclude from your answer?!

Comment: Yes. It seems so.

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable function is **not** monotonic if there are two different points whose derivatives have different signs. Since $x' = -\frac{rx + a\ln ( 1 + x/b)}{l}$ is a [composition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142084/prove-that-the-composition-of-differentiable-functions-is-differentiable) of differentiable functions, it's differentiable and thus continuous; if not monotonic, $x'$ it must have a root; *and at least one root is **not** an inflection point*. Simbolically, $$\begin{cases} x'(t) = 0 \\ x''(t) \neq 0\end{cases}$$ for some $t$. But $x'' = -x'\left(r + \frac{a}{b + x}\right)$ so the second derivative is zero on all the roots of the first derivative. So every root is an inflection point and thus, in fact, $x$ **is monotonic**.

Comment: OP: your function is monotonic.